# Is the polyarea() function in geometry package accurate enough to calculate areas in complex polygons?

Tags: r, geometry, polygon

Using data from laser scanners (points in the space), I am trying to build complex polygons and compute their areas, but I am not sure how accurate enough are the available R functions to compute polygons area.

I have used the polyarea() function in the "geometry" package, but also the gArea() function in the "rgeos" package, both with the same result. 
Since the documentation in the two functions gives examples using very simple polygon shapes, I wondering if these functions are able to compute areas for a little more complex polygon, like the one described by my "slice.to.rot" data.

This is the code I use.

```
plot(slice.to.rot[, c(3, 5)], cex=0.01, pch=19)
lines(slice.to.rot[, c(3, 5)])
polygon(slice.to.rot[, c(3, 5)])
polyarea(slice.to.rot[, 3], slice.to.rot[, 5])
```

Next you will find a link to the "slice.to.rot" data to run the code.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12KSTRCOu2wYGMYsvAo-bKAskfD_w2Y1H/view?usp=sharing